How to create 6 job instances with 3 being 'software' and 3 being 'QA' using Laravel Factories?
I'm working with Laravel and need to create 6 job instances using a factory. Out of these 6 jobs, I want 3 to have a type of 'software' and 3 to have a type of 'QA'.
Here’s my current approach using the Job seeder:
 $tags = Tag::factory(3)->create();
    Job::factory(6)->create()->each(function ($job) use ($tags) {
        $tag = $tags->random(3);
        $job->tags()->attach($tag);
    });


I am wondering why you are using the random function when you don't want to have random values.
Consider using this instead: $faker->randomElement(['software', 'QA']) for the name.

thank you I found a way to add with a method called sequence
Tag::factory(3)->create();
$tag = $tags->random(3); this selects 3 random tags and attaches them to the job, I wanted to modify the Job and I found I can do with sequance
